# fetch returns record type that wont cast to Record

Tags: java, sql, generics, jooq

I'm using pretty standard syntax here, I think:

```
Result<Record> = [DSLContext].selectDistinct(...).fetch();
```

but it wont compile because the above returns record objects of type

```
Result<Record4<T1, T2, ...>
```

which is an autogenerated interface, which is a subinterface of Record but the compiler remains unhappy

I suppose normally java will treat this as an implicit cast? doesnt seem like I should be doing any explicit casting...

tips? thanks

Answer (score 1):

If a `List<Banana>` was a `List<Fruit>`, you could add apples to a `List<Banana>`:

```
List<Banana> bananaList = new ArrayList<>();
List<Fruit> fruitList = bananaList;
fruitList.add(new Apple());
```

And it would thus break the type safety of generic types.

You probably want

```
Result<? extends Record> result = [DSLContext].selectDistinct(...).fetch();
```

Comment: You can even conveniently write `Result<?>`, because `<R>` has a declaration-site upper bound of `Record`

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Java does not know declaration-site variance like C# or Scala:

```
// C# style
interface Result<out Record> { ... }

// Scala style
trait Result[+Record] { ... }
```

Both of the above would allow assigning the following

```
Result<Record4<T1, ...>> r1 = ...
Result<Record> r2 = r1;
```

But [`Result`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Result.html) is really defined as:

```
interface Result<R extends Record> {}
```

Now, since your query expression binds `<R>` to `Record4<T1, ...>`, this is what you're going to get:

```
Result<Record4<T1, ...>> r1 = selectDistinct(...).fetch();
```

Alternatively, you can just use a wild-card

```
Result<? extends Record> r2 = r1;

// Or shorter:
Result<?> r3 = r1;
```

Another option is to force removal of typesafety when expressing your query:

```
Result<Record> r4 = selectDistinct(new Field[] { ... }).fetch();
```

Comment: @toilinginobscurity: Which part helped the most? :-)

Comment: hi lukas - what I really needed was a mini tutorial in generics, wildcards, etc -- which I got! jooq is cool, thanks for all your hard work